# What is the most effective/conventional way to remove an item from a React component state?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

After working with AngularJS, i find the immutability of React state a bit tedious. For example, i needed to just remove an item by its ID, from an array on the state. This is the state:

```
 state = {       
    pages: []
 }
```

And this is the removal of the item from the array, after the DELETE ajax has succeeded:

```
 deletePage = (id)=>{
   ajax(`/content/${id}/delete`,'delete')
   .then(({data})=>{
     if(data.status === 'ok'){
       let stateClone = _.cloneDeep(this.state);
       stateClone.pages = stateClone.pages.filter(page=> page.id != id);
       console.log('newstate')
       this.setState(()=>(stateClone))
     }

    })
  }
```

I know it looks ridiculous, especially because of the the cloneDeep method. This is just the easiest way i could think of, to achieve this, while avoiding any mutation to the original state.

What is the convention around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a React problem.. it's a JavaScript problem since nested objects are by reference.

This code:

```
let stateClone = _.cloneDeep(this.state);
stateClone.pages = stateClone.pages.filter(page=> page.id != id);
console.log('newstate')
this.setState(()=>(stateClone))
```

Would typically be rewritten as:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  pages: state.pages.filter(page => page.id !== id)
}))
```

Because top level keys are preserved when calling `setState` so you don't need to clone them. Even if they weren't though, you could do:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state, // not needed for React's `setState`
  pages: state.pages.filter(page => page.id !== id)
}))
```

Try to keep your state flat. This is advice for all applications, not just React ones.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much